# Grabbing the Value of a Form and Using POST

Tags: html, forms, http-post

Would like to post the value of a dynamic selection menu when the OnChange event is called. My code is currently this:

```
<form action="test4.php" method="POST" name="itemform">
<select name="input_name" id="input_name" onChange="this.form.submit();">
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        echo "<option value='".$row['item_id']."'>" . $row['itemname'] . "</option>";
?>
</form>
```

The option values are populated by a query defined above and that works like a charm. The problem I am facing is for some reason the form is not grabbing and POSTing the value selected in the menu box when the OnChange event is raised. Any Ideas?

Comment: How are you attempting to retrieve the posted value?

Comment: My page test4.php uses this line to retrieve the value:

echo ($_GET["input_name"]);

@Mech, Where should I put that in place of?

Comment: then obviously you would need to change your form to `method="GET"` -or- your test4.php to `$_POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<form action="test4.php" method="POST" name="itemform">`
>
> My page test4.php uses this line to retrieve the value: echo ($_GET["input_name"]);

You're mixing up `$_GET` and `$_POST`, you need to use the one that corresponds to your form's `method`.

Answer (score 0):

Close your `<select>` tag. ;D

Comment: Good point. Needed to do this thanks! But still not the problem.

Comment: I thought "add comment" was for adding a comment?
I don't mean for this to sound rude, but is there an etiquette guide we should be following?

Answer (score -1):

Try closing your `<select>` element - that could be it.

Comment: Good point. Needed to do this thanks! But still not the problem.